# Session variable is not getting set consistently while logging out and logging back in

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, ejs

I have an issue with my session variable not getting set consistently. Here is my session declaration.

```
app.use(
    session({
        secret: process.env.MYSTERY,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store: store,
        cookie: {
            maxAge : 86400000, // expires in 1 day (in milliseconds)
            httpOnly : true,
            sameSite : "strict"
        }
    })
)
```

Then, I store 'isAuth' and 'username' into session WHEN user logs in successfully. Below is my post route for log in.

```
exports.loginCustomer = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await check('username')
            .custom(async (value) => {
            const customer = await Customer.findOne({ username : value })
            if (!customer) {
                throw new Error('The username or password you entered does not match any account')
            }
            const password = req.body.password;
            const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, customer.password);
            if (!isMatch) {
                throw new Error('The username or password you entered does not match any account');
            }
            return true
            })
            .run(req)
        
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            const alert = errors.array();
            return res.render('./customer/login', { alert, session: req.session });
        }
        const username = req.body.username
        const customer = await Customer.findOne({username})
        req.session.isAuth = true
        req.session.username = username
        req.session.isAdmin = customer.admin
        return res.redirect('/')
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Just in case below is my logout route.

```
exports.logoutCustomer =  async (req, res) => {
    req.session.destroy((err) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err
        } else {
            console.log("LOGOUT")
            res.redirect('../')
        }
    })
}
```

The issue is that session.isAuth and session.username do not get set consistently when the user successfully logs back in after logged out. I have tested many times logging in logging out then logging back it and found out that sometimes those values get set correctly and sometimes they don't. However, I noticed that after user logged in successfully but being not able to render those two values, I could render those values if I refresh the page.

Thank you for any advice, ideas, and suggestions.

I tried changing the order of the lines of code and checking if session.isAuth and session.username are set by rendering those two values (using ejs). However, I found out that they do not get rendered consistently.